# When should I publish my Steam page?

Tags: marketing, steam

I developing my game, which still in alpha, and plan to sell it via Steam. I already applied to Steam partnership program and want to publish my 'coming soon' Steam page to start gather wishlists, but it on hold for now.

I don't have any promotional material yet, but people on social media positively reacting to gifs of my game. Is it good idea to publish Steam page right now with temporary thumbnail and screenshots of current version and then change everything later? Or should I make my page appealing first?

Comment: In truth, I would most likely try to make my Steam page appealing, as the saying goes “you only get one first impression”. Additionally, the better your page appeals to the audience, the more likely you will be able to attract potential customers and thus market your game more.

Comment: What's the title of your game so we can take a look at it when it's approved? :)

Comment: @Casey I am sorry, but It still under working title

Comment: Definitely don't post it until you make your page look great.  The page is the first thing people see, if you don't make it look professional and interesting it may make them take a negative view of your game.  =)

Answer (score 5):

Wait until what marketing materials you do have represent what the game will look like at launch. That way, people will be more interested in your game.

I also recommend reviewing the documentation for release and the review process, particularly [Store Presence](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store), [Review Process](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/review_process) and [Release Process](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/releasing).

They explicitly state as part of the checklist that you need to have your store page (i.e. promotional materials) ready and approved before releasing and it must include images and/or footage of **actual gameplay available at launch**. You are discouraged from changing it later.

> (italizied emphasis mine)
>
> - **Your store page should only contain features and content that will be available at launch**
>
>   You will need to remove screenshots, trailers, or features listed that contain content that are incomplete or planned to be implemented. *If you include content that's planned to be implemented later in your description section, it will need to be clear that the feature is currently not released*.
> - ...
> - **Your screenshots must only contain gameplay.**
>
>   This means avoid using concept art, pre-rendered cinematic stills, or images that contain awards, marketing copy, or written product descriptions.